# SystemVerilog assertion scheduling

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

A SystemVerilog assertion is latching the previous values even though the transition is detected.

I have the below property as part of the file. `a` and `b` are inputs whose width is 1-bit.

```
property p_sig_detect();
    @(a,b)
    (a == 1) -> (b == 1);
endproperty

a_sig_detect : assert property(p_sig_detect());
```

In the above code, the assertion is behaving like below:

```
  1. At 0 ,    a = 0,       b = 0 (initial state)  --> No effect
  2. At t1,    a = 0->1,    b = 0                  --> Passing
  3. At t2,    a = 1,       b = 0->1               --> Throwing Error saying that "b" is 0
  4. At t3,    a = 1,       b = 1->0               --> Passing
  5. At t4&t5, a = 1->0->1, b = 0                  --> Throwing Error once a becomes 1 at t5
```

Can someone please explain why it's latching the previous value even though the transition is detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampled values used in a synchronous assertion are the values in the preponed region *before* the clocking event.

You should be using immediate or deferred assertions that do not use clocks or sample values instead of concurrent assertions and properties that do.

```
module top;
  bit a,b;
  
  initial begin
    #1 a = 1;
    #1 b-= 1;
    #1 a = 0;
    #1 b = 0;
    #1 $finish;
  end
  
  let p_sig_detect = (a == 1) -> (b == 1);

  always_comb
    a_sig_detect : assert (p_sig_detect()) $info("pass"); else $error("fail");
endmodule
```